# XNA Shader has an unwanted tint

Tags: xna, shaders

I'm working on a shader but it has a weird tint to it and I'm not sure why. Right now it's extremely simple, it just sets a rendertarget, draws to it, passes it as a texture to the shader then oututs the pixels to a fullscreen quad. If I remove the rendertarget/texture part and just directly pass it into the shader it comes out properly, but once I start including rendertargets the colors get a little weird.

Here are two images showing what I mean:

This is how it should look normally

[image: This is how it should look normally]

This is how it looks with the rendertargets
[image: This is how it looks with the rendertargets]
I've included the code for the shader and the draw method below:

Shader:

```
float4x4 World;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;

Texture glowTexture;

sampler glowSampler = sampler_state 
{ 
texture = <glowTexture>;
magfilter = LINEAR;
minfilter = LINEAR;
mipfilter = LINEAR;
AddressU = clamp;
AddressV = clamp;
};

struct VertexShaderInput
{
float4 Position : POSITION0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
float4 Position : POSITION0;
};

VertexShaderOutput VSOutline(VertexShaderInput input)
{
VertexShaderOutput output;

output.Position = input.Position;

return output;
}

float4 PSOutline(VertexShaderOutput input, float2 pixel:VPOS) : COLOR0
{
float2 uvPixel = (pixel + 0.5) * float2(1.0 / 1280, 1.0 / 770);

float4 finalColor = tex2D(glowSampler, uvPixel);

return finalColor;
}

technique Outline
{
pass Pass1
{
    AlphaBlendEnable = TRUE;
    DestBlend = INVSRCALPHA;
    SrcBlend = SRCALPHA;

    VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VSOutline();
    PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PSOutline();
}
}
```

Draw method:

```
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

            scene.RenderGrid();
            playerList.Render();
            scene.RenderObjects();

            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);


            renderTargetTexture = (Texture2D)renderTarget;

            for (int l = 0; l < resourceLoader.GlowShader.CurrentTechnique.Passes.Count; l++)
            {
                resourceLoader.GlowShader.Parameters["glowTexture"].SetValue(renderTargetTexture);

                resourceLoader.GlowShader.CurrentTechnique.Passes[l].Apply();
                renderQuad.Render();
            }
```

Comment: I think that you only haven't clean rendertarget to black before drawing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is either that the SpriteBatch changes the GraphicsDevice states or that you haven't cleared your rendertarget like Vodáček suggested.

For more information on the device states see [BlendState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.blendstate.aspx) and the others

Comment: Aha, thanks you two, it was because I wasn't clearing it. I didn't realise I had to clear it on both rendertargets and the second wasn't being cleared

Comment: Search for "xna purple background" and there will be tons of information. Purple background is always a hint from XNA that something went wrong while changing render targets.